# search end users ipaddress by their username

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

Hi I'm trying to do a PowerShell search that I'm able to input the end users SAMaccountName and it to push out the computer IPv4 address that they are logged into.

When trying to run the script it asks for a Class: and wont give me an IPv4 address for the user.

```
$selectUser = Read-Host 'What is the endusers username?'
$compname = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Properties ipv4Address | select Name
ForEach($device in $compname) {
    $usr = Get-WmiObject –ComputerName $device | Select-Object UserName
    if($usr -eq $selectUser){
        $compip = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Properties ipv4Address | select ipv4Address
    }
}
```

cmdlet Get-WmiObject at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Class: 
PS C:\Windows\system32>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as the prompt indicates, you need to supply a value for the `-Class` parameter of [`Get-WmiObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-wmiobject); it's required.  Based on your use of the `UserName` property, it looks like you want the [`Win32_ComputerSystem` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-computersystem)...

```bsh
$usr = Get-WmiObject –ComputerName $device -Class Win32_ComputerSystem | Select-Object UserName
```

Also, because you are using the (positional) `-Property` parameter of [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Select-Object) to retrieve the `UserName` property, `$usr` will not contain the `UserName` property directly but instead an object with a single `UserName` property.  Your condition in the following `if` statement, `$usr -eq $selectUser`, will not behave as you expect.

To fix this, compare against the `$usr.UserName` property instead...

```bsh
if($usr.UserName -eq $selectUser){
```

Alternatively, to have `$usr` store the `UserName` text directly you can use the `-ExpandProperty` parameter of `Select-Object`...

```bsh
$usr = Get-WmiObject –ComputerName $device -Class Win32_ComputerSystem | Select-Object -ExpandProperty UserName
if($usr -eq $selectUser){
```

...or use member syntax to retrieve the `UserName` property...

```bsh
$usr = (Get-WmiObject –ComputerName $device -Class Win32_ComputerSystem).UserName
if($usr -eq $selectUser){
```